# How can I help tox find the correct version of python on windows?

Tags: python, windows, tox

I'm working on getting `tox` running on Windows for an open source project I'm fooling around with.

Inside `tox.ini` there are a few sections that specify `basepython`

```
[testenv:pylint]
basepython = python3
ignore_errors = True
deps =
  ...
```

Unfortunately, the default installations of python just provide `python.exe` in the path, so `python3` is not found causing failures.

Is there a "proper way" to deal with this in tox?  Is there anyway that I can provide a basepython fallback when one isn't found.  I could manually copy `python.exe` to `python3.exe` but that could cause problem with the way `tox` creates virtual environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first check if it is somewhere explained in the docs of that project how this should work on Windows. If it is not documented, I would ask the maintainer(s) of the project if and how this should work with a default installation of Windows.

If this was something that was just not yet thought of in that project (maybe because they all develop on Mac and Linux) you can figure out a solution together that works for all developers.

for example: the tox.ini could be modified like this:

```
[testenv:pylint]
basepython = {env:PYTHON3_PATH:python3}
ignore_errors = True
deps =
...
```

That way you can override the basepython if this is necessary on your system

Also see [tox docs about environment variable substitution](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#environment-variable-substitutions).

Comment: Unfortunately I’m probably one of the small minority working on windows at the moment.  Your environment vary able substitution looks like it should work wonderfully though.